# What's difference between events in Winforms and commands in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, events

In Winforms we (developers) handle user interactions via events.
In WPF we got commands.

Questions :

1. what's difference between events in Winforms and commands in WPF? Which approach we must use? and when?
2. what's difference between events in Winforms and routed events in WPF?

Comment: I'd highly recommend starting out by reading through [MSDN's article on Routed Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx)

Comment: There are also plain events in WPF, commands and routed events are just an addition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Command represented by an object which could be serialized, passed over a process, whatever, let's say it is more "flexible".
2. Routed Events supports [next strategies - direct, bubbling and tunneling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx#routing_strategies), also using routed event you can indicate that event was processed by settign an appropriate flag in event arguments.

Comment: 1. on which situations we must serialized command? I dont understand it.
2. Thanks. I forget about flag.

Comment: @ZuTa - That is an entirely new question.  Come up with a single question and post it.

Comment: @sll - Thanks. I have created a new question.

Answer (score 2):

I'd highly recommend starting out by reading through [MSDN's article on Routed Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx), however from my point of view, the biggest difference is how they work

Winforms lets you assign an method to an event handler, and whenever that control's event is raised, that handler gets run. You can actually do the same thing in WPF, or you can use a Routed Event.

In a Routed Event, an event is generated (such as a click event), and the any element in the Visual Tree can subscribe to do something during the Click event, and can mark the Event as handled or not.

For example, suppose you have a `Button` containing a `Border` and an `Image`

```
<Button>
    <Border>
        <Image>
    </Border>
</Button>
```

Clicking on the `Image` doesn't execute `Button.ClickEvent`, but instead simply raises a generic `Click` event which is processed by the `Image` first, then the `Border`, and then the `Button`. The event will actually continue up the VisualTree until it hits the `Window` object, unless one of the controls handling the event marks it as `Handled`

This type of Routed event is called a `Bubbling` event because the event travels, or "bubbles", up the Visual Tree. Another event type is `Tunneling`, where the event travels down the VisualTree, or `Direct`, where only the object that got clicked processes the event.

As for the difference between `Routed Events` and `Commands`, they provide two separate functions. Events are built-in and are tied with the UI object that is handling the Event, while a Command is not tied to the UI object in any way, and provides built-in support for enabling/disabling controls.

For example, a Button with a `Click` event will pass the Button object into the Click event handler, while a Button with the `Command` property set will execute an unrelated command and automatically enable/disable the button depending on `Command.CanExecute()`

I use the MVVM design pattern, so almost always use Commands (if a control doesn't support the `Command` property, I use a custom [Attached Command Behavior](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/) which lets me attach a command to almost any UI event), however I still use Events on occasion when I want to do something that affects the View only and doesn't do any business logic.